# linking to the index.html to other html page in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am new to the Django project.
I have been trying to create a situation in which, when a user presses the "Call us now" button in my nav-bar, it links them to other html pages (here: contact.html). How can I adjust what I have to achieve this?

Here are my files:
index.html

```
code:   </ul><a href="contact.html"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">call us now!</button></a></div>
```

views.py

```
        from django.shortcuts import render


                  def index(request):
                      return render(request, 'jobs/index.html')

                  def contacts(request):
                      return render(request, 'jobs/contact.html')
```

in the urls.py

```
                  urlpatterns = [
                           path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                           path('', jobs.views.index, name='index'),
                           path('contact/', jobs.views.contacts, name='contact'),] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)**
```

Comment: You have an error - in your path name should be "contacts" not "contact"

Answer (score 1):

Change

`href="contact.html"`

To :

```
href="{% url 'contact' %}"
```